# Tag merge request: history and church-history

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags which I thought ought to be merged:

[history](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has 288 questions, and the tag wiki says `Church history is the chronicle ....`

[church-history](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/church-history) has only 68 questions, with a tag wiki that says `Dealing with the history of the Church`

If these tags aren't duplicates, one of the tag wikis needs to be updated accordingly. :)

Comment: Without taking a closer look, I'll bet these tags need to stay separate, but many questions need to be retagged, and yes one of the tag wikis (history) needs to be updated.

Comment: @El'endiaStarman: That's probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should be separate tags, and I've proposed some tag wiki edits to make the difference clear.

A further tag to consider is [early-church](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/early-church). Currently its description says 200. Is that the best date for the tag? Would it be useful to have a tag for the NT era church?